# Discrepancy between downstream response time clocked within service & actual downstream endpoint response time

Tags: node.js, performance, next.js

we have a nodejs based application that have one dependent downstream service call. Total response time logged from the actual downstream endpoint is **~300ms**, where within our service total time logged for the same downstream call is **~600ms**, almost **two times difference**. We are using **fetch** for our network calls, the network time is usually **30~40ms**, and there's no other hop between our service and downstream service. All the numbers are fetched from result of 10TPS perf test.

Additionally, we have tried to use custom-agent in our network calls for utilizing connection pooling. Originally we were only using fetch with default agent. Then we added in a custom-agent with the following settings:

```
https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
    maxSockets: 30,
    keepAliveMsecs: 5000
    maxTotalSockets: 256,
});
```

And thought it would improve connection time, but surprisingly, there was no change in performance compared to the previous default agent calls.

Any ideas on why there's discrepancy between the timing? And why the custom-agent option had no effect on performance? Thank you!

Comment: What switches, proxies, firewalls, and routers is traffic being sent through? The problem could exist at any of those points.

Comment: None of those are taking time. It is definitely on the app. If we reduce the tps, we are seeing better numbers

Comment: If the calls to the endpoint, without fetch, is normal, as well as the endpoint itself, then it could be that your app is blocking the event queue and that your fetch is blocked for 300ms before it finally executes.  Do you have other code before that fetch that's adding blocking stuff to the event queue?

Comment: When the request is made to the downstream api then there must be some latency because of waiting to process the request. Once the request starts processing it took 300 ms. Then the response reaching your network is again creating overhead.
The only possible reason i can see is either your downstream stream server is throttling to process the request or may be the proxies or firewall is taking time to bypass the request. 
Will it be possible for you to try to deploy the app in the same downstream server?